# Google Drive API "computer or network may be sending automated queries" requesting with API Key

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, request, google-drive-api

I've been using the Google Drive API to crawl a certain folder in order to load the files in the folder to an app I am making. I am using an API key created from google console, and was under the assumption that as long as I did not pass the rate limit for requests I would be able to request data from Google Drive.

However, google responds with a `403 Forbidden` with the response html

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/><title>Sorry...</title><style> body { font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; background-color: #fff; color: #000; }</style></head><body><div><table><tr><td><b><font face=sans-serif size=10><font color=#4285f4>G</font><font color=#ea4335>o</font><font color=#fbbc05>o</font><font color=#4285f4>g</font><font color=#34a853>l</font><font color=#ea4335>e</font></font></b></td><td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: bottom; padding-bottom: 15px; width: 50%"><div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;">Sorry...</div></td></tr></table></div><div style="margin-left: 4em;"><h1>We're sorry...</h1><p>... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now.</p></div><div style="margin-left: 4em;">See <a href="https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640">Google Help</a> for more information.<br/><br/></div><div style="text-align: center; border-top: 1px solid #dfdfdf;"><a href="https://www.google.com">Google Home</a></div></body></html>
```

[image: Response Screenshot]

I am not sure why Google protects against automated queries considering my API key is not a client user and I made it to use automated queries without requiring Oauth. All my requested files are publicly viewable on the web, and therefore I was hoping to avoid the need for Oauth to run the requests.

I know similar questions have been asked before, but all required the use of Oauth, which is what I am trying to avoid. Is there a method similar to using `Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN` or alternatives that can be done solely with an API key?

A quick overview of what my code does is essentially a series of get requests and export requests for various files in a folder to download. It sends one get request at a time, and crawls through every file and subfolder in a folder. If you want some more detailed code, I have included the crawler code below.

```
const driveTools = {
    getFolder: (drive, id) => drive.files.list({q:`'${id}' in parents`}),
    get: (drive, id, extra) => drive.files.get(Object.assign({fileId:id}, extra)),
    export: (drive, id, mimeType) => drive.files.export({fileId:id, mimeType:mimeType})
}

function dataURI(mimeType, response){
    let data = Buffer.from(response.data, 'utf8').toString('base64');
    let ret = {download:`<a href="data:${mimeType};base64,${data}" target="_blank">`}
    switch(true){
        case /application\/pdf/.test(mimeType):
            ret = Object.assign(ret,{html:`<embed src="data:${mimeType};base64,${data}"/>`});
            break;
        case /image\/.+/.test(mimeType):
            ret = Object.assign(ret,{html:`<img src="data:${mimeType};base64,${data}"/>`});
            break;
    }
    return ret;
}

/*
 * Used to load and compile the curriculum folder into JSON format
*/
async function load(params){
    const drive = google.drive({
        version:'v3',
        auth:params.API_KEY
    });

    let crawl = async (fID) => { // crawl subitems given folder
        return await driveTools.getFolder(drive, fID).then(async val=>{
            const out = [];
            for(const x of val.data.files){
                console.log(`resolving ${x.mimeType} ${x.name}`);
                switch(true){
                    case /application\/vnd\.google-apps\.folder/.test(x.mimeType):
                        out.push(await crawl(x.id));
                        break;
                    case /application\/vnd\.google-apps\.document/.test(x.mimeType):
                    case /application\/vnd\.google-apps\.presentation/.test(x.mimeType):
                    case /application\/vnd\.google-apps\.spreadsheet/.test(x.mimeType):
                        x.mimeType = 'application/pdf'
                        out.push(await driveTools.export(drive, x.id, 'application/pdf').then(val=>{return Object.assign(
                                x, {data:dataURI(x.mimeType, val), mimeType:x.mimeType}
                            )}))
                        break;
                    case /video\/.+/.test(x.mimeType): //no videos bad
                        out.push(x)
                        break;
                    default:
                        // weird filetype, just export as self
                        out.push(await driveTools.get(drive, x.id, {alt:'media'}).then(val=>{return Object.assign(
                                x, {data:dataURI(x.mimeType, val)}
                            )}))
                }
            }
            return out;
        }).then(val=>{return {type:'folder',data:val}})
    }

    return await crawl(params.FOLDER_ID);
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code related to the request you're making? Also, has any request worked, or it just started failing after several requests?

Comment: The code is essentially a bunch of drive.file.get requests. It runs for small folders, but fails after a certain timeframe because google realizes the requests are automated, and essentially gives a "we think you're a bot, so we can't give you any more response data." I am trying to bypass that as my API key is made from google console and my intent was to write a program to automate requests.

Comment: I'm thinking you could reduce the amount of requests by calling the API via [batch requests](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch). If you think this could be appropriate to your case, I'd consider posting an answer.